# An efficient way to apply a function over a list of dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, lapply

I have a list of dataframes in R. What I need to do is apply a function to each dataframe, in this case removing special characters, and have returned a list of dataframes.

Using `lapply` and `as.data.frame` the following works fine and delivers exactly what I need:

```
my_df =data.frame(names = seq(1,10), chars = c("abcabc!!", "abcabc234234!!"))
my_list = list(my_df, my_df, my_df)

#str(my_list)
List of 3
 $ :'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables: ...

new_list <- lapply(my_list, function(y) as.data.frame(lapply(y, function(x) gsub("[^[:alnum:][:space:]']", "", x))))

# str(new_list)
List of 3
 $ :'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ names: Factor w/ 10 levels "1","10","2","3",..: 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 2
  ..$ chars: Factor w/ 2 levels "abcabc","abcabc234234": 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
 $ :'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ names: Factor w/ 10 levels "1","10","2","3",..: 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 2
  ..$ chars: Factor w/ 2 levels "abcabc","abcabc234234": 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
 $ :'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ names: Factor w/ 10 levels "1","10","2","3",..: 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 2
  ..$ chars: Factor w/ 2 levels "abcabc","abcabc234234": 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
```

But I am wondering if there is a more efficient way that doesn't require nested `lapply`. Perhaps a different apply-family function that returns the elements as a dataframe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't need a nested `lapply`, just a single `lapply` with `transform` does it

```
lapply(my_list, transform, chars = gsub("[^[:alnum:][:space:]']", "", chars))
```

The pattern can be made compact to `"[^[[:alnum:] ']"`

Comment: Thank you akrun (and for introducing me to the transform function).

Answer (score 1):

While @akrun is right that your second `lapply` call is useless in this example, I think it does not solve the general case where many columns might be relevant, and it is unknown which might be.

What is inefficient here is the conversion back with `as.data.frame`, not the inner `lapply` call. The `lapply` call itself is almost just as fast as if you would apply the function to a single vector or a matrix of the same size.

If you really want to be more time-efficient here, I would suggest using `data.table`. I've made the example a bit larger so we can time it.

```
library(data.table)

f <- function(x) gsub("[^[:alnum:][:space:]']", "", x)

my_df <- as.data.frame(matrix(paste0(sample(c(letters,'!'), size=1000000, replace=T),
                                 sample(c(letters,'!'), size=1000000, replace=T)), 
                                 ncol=250), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
my_list = list(my_df, my_df, my_df)

system.time(lapply(my_list, function(y) as.data.frame(lapply(y, f))))
# 2.256 seconds

my_dt <- as.data.table(my_df)
my_list2 = list(my_dt, my_dt, my_dt)

system.time(lapply(my_list2, function(y) y[,lapply(.SD,f)]))
# 1.180 seconds
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer, thanks. Although I was vague with my definition of efficient, what I meant was actually efficient in a code sense. But good to know that dt is more efficient too :)